# When to use websockets perMessageDeflate?

Tags: websocket, compression

I have been unable to find good information as to the usefulness/practicality of the perMessageDeflate option/module.

Suppose I have messages that are 1000 bites (the length of the text string), being sent out 10 times per second (every 100 ms), is compression worth it there?

I have heard that perMessageDeflate can be a monster on CPU usage. I imagine it is not cost-effective if your messages are really small and infrequent.

Anyway, does anyone have any idea what the threshold is? At what point in packet size and frequency (i.e. bandwidth) is using perMessageDeflate a smart idea?

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to get a canonical information, but I would say that for less than 500 bytes it does not make sense.

Last time I checked, only Google Chrome supported WebSocket compression. Also, it can work without "context takeover" if either client or server request such thing, so the overall compression ratio is lower (because a new context is used for each message).

As pretty much everything when it comes to performance: first measure current performance to get a baseline, then enable it and then measure again.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31750/what-is-recommended-minimum-object-size-for-gzip-performance-benefits

http://www.itworld.com/article/2693941/cloud-computing/why-it-doesn-t-make-sense-to-gzip-all-content-from-your-web-server.html